# Spring Security shows default login instead of OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am writing a `RESTful` web service (Jersey running on Tomcat) that needs to authenticate users. The plan is to redirect them to login to Google via `OAuth2`. Once they grant us permission to see their email address, we'll know if they are a known user in our system.

I am using `Spring Security`. I had it working with basic authentication (hard-wired list of users and passwords.)  Then I added `OAuth2` elements to the XML configuration, but when I access the service from a browser I'm still getting prompted to login by the browser, instead of getting redirected to Google's website. There are no particular errors logged by the console.

Suggestions would be appreciated. Here is my Spring Security configuration file: spring-security.xml (though without the real client's ID and secret.)

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" 

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd">

<debug/>

<oauth:client id="oauth2ClientFilter" />

<oauth:resource id="googleOauth2Resource" type="authorization_code" client-id="myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com" client-secret="myclientsecret" 
    access-token-uri="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v3/token" user-authorization-uri="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" scope="email" />

<http auto-config='true' xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/V1/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
</http>

<oauth:rest-template id="googleOauthRestTemplate" resource="googleOauth2Resource" />

<authentication-manager>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Here are the guts of my `web.xml` file. (Nothing here was changed from when I had the hard-wired list of users and passwords.)

```
<!-- Require HTTPS for everything except /img (favicon) and /css. -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOrHTTP</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint> 


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.foobar.dataservices</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/V1/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<resource-ref>
    <description>TAE DB Connection Pool</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/taeDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<listener>  
  <listener-class>
   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener  
  </listener-class>  
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Suggestions for getting `OAuth2` working would be most appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Are there SO guidelines for when to use backticks? For example, is web.xml quoted because it is such a common element, or should all filenames be written that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing *auto-config="true"* from the http element in *spring-security.xml* got rid of the wrong login form.

This revealed a new error:

> Configuration problem: No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be
>   established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured
>   through the namespace (such as form-login)  or specify a custom
>   AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute

So I added the missing `entry-point-ref`, and an `access-denied-handler` while I was at it:

```
<http xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/V1/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
</beans:bean>
```

The service now launches without logging any errors and does not show the wrong login form.

(But note that it denies permission to all my resources. I thought `Spring Security` would redirect to Google on behalf of my `RESTful` service, but maybe my webpage needs to get the authorization token before calling the service? I think that's a new topic though.)